# Cannot access function that is inside a case class - scala

Tags: scala, function, rdd, case-class

I am trying to make a RDD of k-nearest neighbors from points inside each Bounding Box. I have these case classes inside the object KNN:

```
object KNN extends App{
    def buildtree(points: Seq[Seq[T]], depth: Int = 0): Option[KdNode[T]]
    case class BoundingBox[T](lowerleft_X: T, lowerleft_Y: T, upperright_X: T, upperright_Y: T)
    case class KdNode[T](value: Seq[T], left: Option[KdNode[T]], right: Option[KdNode[T]], axis: Int)
    {
        def Knearest(to: Seq[T]): Seq[Nearest[T]] = {....}
    }
    case class Nearest[T](value: Seq[T], to: Seq[T], distance: Double)
}
```

First, I made a Pair RDD of kdtree with key = BoundingBox and Value = Option[KdNode[T]] by using the below line of code. Here, buildtree is a function defined inside the object and PointsRDD is also a PairRDD. This works fine:

```
val kdtree = PointsRDD.mapValues(p => buildtree(p))
```

Type of kdtree is RDD[BoundingBox[T],Option[KdNode[T]].

Then, when I try to call the Knearest function on kdtree, the Knearest symbol is not recognized.

I am trying to call Knearest using mapValues and also tried it in a for loop, but both approaches do not work, that is it gives the error "cannot resolve symbol Knearest" (error for both; for loop and mapValues)

```
val knn = kdtree.mapValues(node => Knearest(node))
for (kd <- kdtree; knearest = kd Knearest to)
```

where, to is the point from which k-nearest neighbors are to be searched.

I am doing something wrong here, but I cannot figure out what, since I am fairly new to Scala. Please help in this regard. Thanks.

Comment: Edited the question. Type of val kdtree is RDD[BoundingBox[T],Option[KdNode[T]] and the error is same both times; cannot resolve symbol Knearest

Comment: If `Knearest` is a method on `node` (why start with a capital?), it should be `mapValues(node => node.Knearest(others)`.

Comment: What Thilo says won't quite work because `node` is an `Option[KdNode[T]]`, not `KdNode[T]` itself. Either match on `Some` and `None` cases,  or use one of `Option` methods (`map`, `fold`...)